# STR type not changing to INT in Python 2.7

Tags: python

I have a script i'm trying to piece together. It does alot of number shuffling and whatnot, it records resource utilization on the local machine. I am hung up on part of the script. I am trying to create an int from part of a string. Here is the problematic portion of the script...

```
j = item[11:len(item)]
if j.endswith("L"):
    j = int(j[0:len(j)-1])
print type(j)
```

item is a string that is gotten from a long series of string slicing/splitting. In this case, item would equal something similar to this - " bytes_recv=3829381938203L" or " bytes_recv=1302". These four lines will trim the non-decimal characters, then remove the trailing L if there is one, then print the type of the variable J which in  my head should be an integer because of line three in my code, where it sets it to int with int(). When I run the script it never fails to tell me the j variable type is 'str'. This is making my script throw up on itself when it hits this next line of code,

```
sndf = int(((float(int(j) - ndic[nds][len(ndic[nds])-1])/1024)/1024))
```

the ndic dictionary contains running lists of data points from the resource monitoring for use in graphing later. That line of code is taking the last entry from the dictionary key's list, and subtracting it from our j value, then dividing that total by 1024, twice. I'm not thinking the above line of code is contributing to the error, but it might be so I included it. Here is the error I get when I execute the script,

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
```

I receive that error on the sndf ='s line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that you don't convert `j` to an `int` if it doesn't end with `"L"`.

When I run your script with `item = 'bytes_recv=3829381938203L'`, it works fine, and `j` is an `int`, but with `item  = 'bytes_recv=1302'`, the code in the if block is not executed, so no conversion is done.

If you use `long()` instead of `int()`, you can actually leave the `"L"` there and won't even need the `if` statement:

```
j = long(j[0:len(j)])
```

Comment: Agreed. As a matter of habit, I tend to consider all logical possibilities and deal with them explicitly, so nothing gets left out. It means more lines of code, but it also means less ambiguity on things that haven't been dealt with.

Comment: This is not what is causing the exception, because he does call `int(j)` on the line that does the subtraction.

Comment: This is the closest answer provided and pointing me in the correct direction, I was not converting the j variable to int when I needed to, only when I was slicing off the L. I simply added the line j = int(j) after the if statement, and declared int on j in my line that does the subtraction, and it worked! Was just something simple and I needed to be nudged in the right direction, thanks for that nudge @omz and interjay.

Comment: This is incorrect. `int(j)` is returning an int - if not, it would raise an exception. In addition, the types mentioned in the error message follow the order of the operands - because `str` is mentioned second, the right-hand operand to the `-` operator is the `str`.

Comment: Do long types and int's play nicely when your doing math generally?

Comment: @0xhughes Yes. Try `1L - 2`.

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't magically convert types. `ndic[nds][len(ndic[nds])-1]` is also a string.

Comment: @0xhughes Automatic typecasting from strings is a Bad Idea -- it's one of the many things that makes PHP error-prone.

Comment: So i've been told that int isn't a magical int maker, and that auto typecasting is a bad idea. I appreciate the information, but how do either of you fine gentlemen propose I consider approaching these lines of code?

Comment: @0xhughes Just explicitly convert it to an `int`, using `int`, like you do the left operand.

Comment: Oh gotcha, I misread your answer then. I thought you were stating that using int() wasn't going to magically convert my type to int, and that ndic[nds]... portion of my subtraction was also a string. I see now that you meant python wouldn't magically convert my ndic[nds] portion to an int type. Thanks for the info @Marcin :)

Comment: @Marcin I never thought it did. Which is why I am fumbling around with int() all over my code. Using it in the correct places is my issue here I believe.

Comment: @0xhughes How do you not know the type of object you have stored in your own data structure?

Comment: @Marcin Forgive me if i'm off base here, but the wording of your answer and what you just commented almost seems demeaning. It's always tough to tell on the internet though. Is that a legitimate question? If so forgive me, but i'm not Python wizard. I sling together dirty code to try and get things done at work for odd ball tasks I do, in order to save time. I do appreciate all constructive input and insights.

Comment: @0xhughes You don't need to be a wizard to know that what you put into a datastructure is what you get out. I'm genuinely surprised that you would not know what is in a datastructure you created. Keeping track of types is a fundamental programming task. If you struggle with it, you might like to try working in a language which statically and pervasively typed - avoiding this sort of problem is what they are for. Languages with untyped variables are premised on the assumption that keeping track of types is fairly easy.